# Swf video on iPad / iPhone frame or view?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, flash

Say I want to play some SWF animations on my iOS device, either local or hosted-videos. It doesn't make any difference to me.

I know SWF are banned from Objective-C frameworks, but is there any possible way? Using a view-framework or whatever to make this happen within my App?

The issue is that the videos in SWF are so much lighter than MP4 videos...

I guess no Flash player may be added...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not totally true. You can use open source SWF players like [Gnash](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/)/[LightSpark](http://lightspark.github.io) in your app. But I think you will face app-store deployment issues if you try them. However, if you are planning for some in-house app, you might give them a try.

Comment: Thank you, no in house App, most definitely I want go App Store, so that kind of issues may discourage me from using it.

Comment: It seems pretty tricky to do it straight, there's no other way around?